# How to identify bar click event in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

It seems the `onValueSelected` listener is triggered whenever the chart is clicked -- not when a specific bar is selected. I have also noticed this in the sample app for the library (A bar is highlighted even if I click way above it). I would like to limit the click event to the actual bar that is displayed only, this isn't possible at the moment because the listener is even triggered when the white space between bars is tapped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried chart.setMaxHighlightDistance(float distanceDp)?

Comment: setting `setMaxHighlightDistance` to about 2.5f somehow acts as acceptable but not perfect.

Comment: does anyone has soln to this issue?